# Reusing Simple Keyboard component in same view file Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have created a form using Vuetify and to fill each form field i am trying to add simple keyboard component. But the component only appears at the position declared for the first time irrespective of which field the pointer in pointing.

Can some help on how it can be done?

Comment: Will probably need more details here. Please follow this one: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and found this question. Since I can not write comments due to my low reputation and since my edit of the original question was rejected, I write this information as an answer, even though it just gives more details to the question.

From their documentation, I assume it should be possible to have multiple keyboards visible: https://hodgef.com/simple-keyboard/documentation/options/baseclass/

I am not sure if they can use independent input fields, though.

What I use at the moment is almost literally their demo: https://hodgef.com/simple-keyboard/editor/?d=hodgef/vue-simple-keyboard/tree/master

I only added an id to the props to pass it to the options as "baseClass", which is not applied, which lead to me adding the id manually in the template (next to the keyboardClass).

So only the first keyboard is rendered, and when I press buttons on it, it fills the second textarea, as somehow it is mapped to that.

This is the keyboard component SimpleKeyboard:

```
<template>
    <div :class="keyboardClass" :id="id"></div>
</template>

<script>
    import Keyboard from "simple-keyboard";
    import "simple-keyboard/build/css/index.css";

    export default {
        name: "SimpleKeyboard",
        props: {
            keyboardClass: {
                default: "simple-keyboard",
                type: String
            },
            input: {
                type: String
            },
            id: {
                type: String
            }
        },
        data: () => ({
            keyboard: null
        }),
        mounted() {
            this.keyboard = new Keyboard({
                onChange: this.onChange,
                onKeyPress: this.onKeyPress
            });
            this.keyboard.setOptions({
                baseClass: this.id,
                newLineOnEnter: true,
                maxLength: this.$parent.data.maxLength,
                layout: {
                    default: [
                        "^ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 \u00DF \u00B4 {bksp}",
                        "{tab} q w e r t z u i o p \u00FC +",
                        "{lock} a s d f g h j k l \u00F6 \u00E4 # {enter}",
                        "{shift} < y x c v b n m , . - {shift}",
                        ".com @ {space}"
                    ],
                    shift: [
                        '\u00B0 ! " \u00A7 $ % & / ( ) = ? ` {bksp}',
                        "{tab} Q W E R T Z U I O P \u00DC *",
                        "{lock} A S D F G H J K L \u00D6 \u00C4 ' {enter}",
                        "{shift} > Y X C V B N M ; : _ {shift}",
                        ".com @ {space}"
                    ]
                },
                display: {
                    '{tab}': 'Tab',
                    '{bksp}': 'Löschen',
                    '{lock}': 'Feststell',
                    '{shift}': 'Umschalt',
                    '{enter}': 'Enter',
                    '{space}': 'Leertaste',
                    '.com': '.de'
                }
            });
        },
        methods: {
            onChange(input) {
                this.$emit("onChange", input);
            },
            onKeyPress(button) {
                this.$emit("onKeyPress", button);

                /**
                 * If you want to handle the shift and caps lock buttons
                 */
                if (button === "{shift}" || button === "{lock}") this.handleShift();
            },
            handleShift() {
                let currentLayout = this.keyboard.options.layoutName;
                let shiftToggle = currentLayout === "default" ? "shift" : "default";

                this.keyboard.setOptions({
                    layoutName: shiftToggle
                });
            }
        },
        watch: {
            input(input) {
                this.keyboard.setInput(input);
            }
        }
    };
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
</style>
```

The parent component ("textModule") looks like this:

```
<template>
    <div class="textModule module_box">
        <h2 class="ue">{{data.question}}</h2>
        <div class="moduleBox_answer--wide">
            <div class="moduleBoxAnswer_inner">
                <!-- todo: when focus, hide all other keyboards, show keyboard for this only -->
                <textarea :id="'Text'+questionId" :maxlength="data.maxLength" :value="input" @input="onInputChange"
                          @focus="showKeyboard(questionId)"
                          class="tile textarea input" placeholder="Tippen Sie hier, um zu schreiben.">
                </textarea>
                <keyboard @onChange="onChange" @onKeyPress="onKeyPress" :input="input" :maxlength="data.maxLength"
                          :id="'keyboard_'+questionId"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <v-btn
                :id="'question_'+questionId+'_submit'"
                class="btn-answerQuestion"
                color="#e86c33"
                v-on:click="$emit('text-value-selected', questionId, getCurrentTextValue())"
        >Antwort abschicken
        </v-btn>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Keyboard from './SimpleKeyboard';
    import $ from 'jquery';

    export default {
        name: "MyKeyboard",
        props: ['questionId', 'data'],
        data: () => ({
            input: "",
        }),
        computed: {
            maxLength() {
                return {...this.data.maxLength}
            }
        },
        components: {keyboard: Keyboard},
        methods: {
            getCurrentTextValue() {
                console.log(this.input);
                return this.input;
            },
            onChange(input) {
                this.input = input;
            },
            onKeyPress(button) {
                console.log("button", button);
            },
            onInputChange(input) {
                console.log("input");
                this.input = input.target.value;
            },
            showKeyboard(keyboard_id) {
                $(".simple-keyboard").hide();
                $("#keyboard_" + keyboard_id).show();
            }
        }
    };
</script>

<style scoped>
    .simple-keyboard {
        display: none; //to hide all until shown onFocus
    }

    /* override bootstrap active state */
    button.btn-default:active {
        background-color: #FFF;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
    }

    button.btn-default:active:hover {
        background-color: #3276B1;
    }

    /* override Bootstrap excessive button padding */
    button.ui-keyboard-button.btn {
        padding: 1px 6px;
    }

    /* Bootswatch Darkly input is too bright */
    .ui-keyboard-input.light, .ui-keyboard-preview.light {
        color: #222;
        background: #ddd;
    }

    .ui-keyboard-input.dark, .ui-keyboard-preview.dark {
        color: #ddd;
        background: #222;
    }

    .textarea {
        border: 1px solid black;
        width: 100%;
        height: 120px;
        resize: none;
        white-space: pre-wrap;
    }
</style>
```

That is called in a loop in another component which handles the complete form

```
<TextModule v-if="question.type === 'Text'" :data="question.questionSpecifics"
                            :questionId="question.id"
                            v-on:text-value-selected="pushTextSurvey"/>
```

The first keyboard is rendered like this:

```
<div data-v-7a331872="" data-v-1b678632="" id="keyboard_1" class="simple-keyboard hg-theme-default hg-layout-default" maxlength="300">keyboard rows here</div>
```

The second keyboard looks the same, with correct id and correct maxlength, only that it does not have any rows in it. So I assume the component logic only looks for the first keyboard template and only fills that with rows.

I would also be okay with having just one keyboard and pushing that around, as long as it still changes different inputs. As in, whenever I focus a new textarea, the keyboard shall change its position and the target binding.